# Sticky transparent navbar on scroll, using video as a background

Tags: video, background, navbar, transparent, sticky

I am trying to make a navbar like in this website

http://spacetrain.com/

(To see the effect you have to click in any of the links of the menu, so you can scroll down.)

As you can see, when you scroll down the navbar, it sticks to the top with some top padding, using the video as background.

I see it use bootstrap Scrollspy, but I am not really sure how can I implement this in my website.

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The navbar on that link doesn't appear to be transparent, it just has a black background. To make a div 'sticky' and stay at the top of the page on scroll, you need to use 'position: fixed'.

```css
#sticky-div {
 position: fixed;
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

#dummy-content {
 background: grey;
 padding: 300px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky-div">
  <p>I stay here</p>
</div>

<div id="dummy-content">
  <p>I don't stick</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. The navbar will be right after the header, that will be a full-width video. What I want to do is make the navbar sticky on scroll, once I scroll down after the header, but also make the bottom of the video sticky aswell, so its part of the navbar. If you check the website and click in any of the links of the page, you can scroll down and see this effect. Many thanks for your help anyway.